# How to create a macOS App from Custom Visual Studio Code Fork?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a macOS app from my custom fork of Visual Studio Code.

I've successfully followed the docs to run the debug build:

```
cd vscode
yarn
yarn watch
./scripts/code.sh
```

Additionally, I've been able to build it using the command:

```
yarn gulp vscode-darwin-arm64-min
```

However, I'm unsure about how to package it into a macOS app.